# Simulink: Cant Build Model due to Reason: "Code generation information file does not exist"

Tags: deployment, raspberry-pi, code-generation, simulink

Hey iam trying to deploy a Simulink Model to an Raspberry Pi 2B but iam running into problems of not finding the needed library for the deployment ("rtw_continuous.h")

Whenever i try to deploy the Model, i get an Error that the requiered directory "rtw_continuous.h" does not exist. Currently it is unclear to me how to include this properly.In the make-File the path to this specific libaray is correctly addressed.I tryed various solution, like uisng pack N go, but non of them worked as accpected.I also tryed to implement it trough Custome Code and specify the directory in there as well (does not work).

This is the Error_Code iam getting:

```
Error executing command "touch -c /home/anonymus1/MATLAB_ws/R2023b/C/Users/anonymus/Desktop/Neue_Version/CONTROL_Record/CAN_Library/Control_SendData_Fast_ert_rtw/*.;
make MATLAB_ROOT=%MATLAB_ROOT% ALT_MATLAB_ROOT=%ALT_MATLAB_ROOT% MATLAB_BIN=%MATLAB_BIN% ALT_MATLAB_BIN=%ALT_MATLAB_BIN%  -j$(($(nproc)+1)) -Otarget -f Control_SendData_Fast.mk all MATLAB_WORKSPACE="/home/anonymus1/MATLAB_ws/R2023b" LINUX_TARGET_LIBS_MACRO="" 
% -C /home/anonymus1/MATLAB_ws/R2023b/C/Users/anonymus/Desktop/Neue_Version/CONTROL_Record/CAN_Library/Control_SendData_Fast_ert_rtw LC_ALL=C". Details:
STDERR: In file included from /home/anonymus1/MATLAB_ws/R2023b/C/Users/anonymus/Desktop/Neue_Version/CONTROL_Record/CAN_Library/Control_SendData_Fast_ert_rtw/Control_SendData_Fast.c:20:
/home/anonymus1/MATLAB_ws/R2023b/C/Users/anonymus/Desktop/Neue_Version/CONTROL_Record/CAN_Library/Control_SendData_Fast_ert_rtw/Control_SendData_Fast.h:25:10: fatal error: rtw_continuous.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include "rtw_continuous.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Control_SendData_Fast.mk:429: Control_SendData_Fast.c.o] Error 1
```

Currently iam using the following Settings to deploy my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2QQH.png)

I would be super thankfull for any advices, even though my explenation seems a bit dizz